# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'windows'

Tags: python-3.7

I'm working on a project and I need to use the PyMouse module.

`pip install pymouse`

installed pymouse correctly, so I assumed all was fine.
However, when importing PyMouse:

`from pymouse import PyMouse`

I got the following error running my program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4opeenrij.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymouse import PyMouseEvent
  File "C:\Users\lcdew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymouse\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from windows import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'windows'
```

I can't seem to figure out what might cause this error message. Any help would be much appreciated.

#### Additional info:

I'm using Python 3.7 32 bit

Current pip version: 18.1

I have Windows 10

working on a 64-bit operating system

Comment: Utilize `pyuserinput` package as `pymouse` [has been merged with the former](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput). Remove pymouse package: `pip uninstall pymouse` and install pyuserinput: `pip install PyUserInput`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had I look into this and became puzzled at first, so looked deeper.
It turns out that pymouse is absolutely full of errors. More that I bothered to find.
The error you got is just one of many errors caused by bad coding.

The code says:

```
from windows import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
```

And it should say:

```
from .windows import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
```

Also, `PyUserInput`, a sister package that is free from the `pymouse` errors, requires `pyhook`, which is unsupported by python 3. After a lot of looking around, the conclusion that there is no way around the problems found, except maybe installing a really early version.

You could also try the keyboard module.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) module. It works on python 3.8, doesn't have any incompatible dependencies, and doesn't seem to have any errors. Once you have the module installed, [this page](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) gives some good examples of various ways to manage the mouse.