# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX' in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop mouse control app with eyes and i'm looking example projects. I'm trying to run source code but I'm getting this error; **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'windows'** in this site, same question already asked from someone but it's never help me.

how can i fix it ?

```
import zmq
from windows import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent

m = PyMouse()
x_dim, y_dim = m.screen_size()

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
smooth_x, smooth_y= 0.5, 0.5

while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    items = msg.split("\n") 
    msg_type = items.pop(0)
    items = dict([i.split(':') for i in items[:-1] ])
    if msg_type == 'Pupil':
        try:
            my_gaze = items['norm_gaze']

            if my_gaze != "None":
                raw_x,raw_y = map(float,my_gaze[1:-1].split(','))

                smooth_x += 0.5 * (raw_x-smooth_x)
                smooth_y += 0.5 * (raw_y-smooth_y)

                x = smooth_x
                y = smooth_y

                y = 1-y 
                x *= x_dim
                y *= y_dim
                x = min(x_dim-10, max(10,x))
                y = min(y_dim-10, max(10,y))

                m.move(x,y)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

After the all codes, I see the error.

***Python Version:*** 3.7.4

***Pip Version:*** 19.2.3

Comment: Whenever you want to use a package, always go to pypi.org/ and search for it and download it on your environment.

In this case, I'm assuming you were expecting https://pypi.org/project/windows/ package to be installed

Comment: Are you running from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Use `python -m pip install windows` in your cmd prompt.

Comment: It just means that your python is missing the windows module for operations

Comment: It's not working. I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

What is windows? Is it a local subpackage that you wrote?
There is a windows package @ pypi but it is only a placeholder by microsoft (without any content).

PyMouse state in their Readme @ github, that PyMouse is merged into PyUserInput (https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput). I would use that instead.

Comment: In original code second line is like this; `import PyMouse` but it's not working. Someone said `from windows import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent` use it. It's not working again. This is same question's link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131954/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-windows)